# Apache Camel - Parallel Routes Inflight Exchanges

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I have a Camel context with many routes that starts every 15m with Timer Component.

These routes set some properties in exchange (Target host, Query and Current Date that I use a Processor to get date, -12 hours and transform to GMT).

After set these properties, using Direct, another route is called to execute the HTTP Get. When the Request finished, another Route is called to Post the return on Artemis ActiveMQ.

The project is deployed on Wildfly 13.

The problem is:
Sometimes the routes simply freeze. Don't start after 15 minutes.
When I try to stop/start the route, I got the follow log:

```
[0m[0m08:27:45,230 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (Camel (camel-example) thread #70 - ShutdownTask) There are 1 inflight exchanges: InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-exchange-ID, fromRouteId=Route1, routeId=GetDataAutoBySinceTime, nodeId=toD7, elapsed=0, duration=216958569]
[0m[0m08:27:46,231 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (Camel (camel-example) thread #70 - ShutdownTask) Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 299 seconds. Inflights per route: [Route1 = 1]
[0m[0m08:27:46,231 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (Camel (camel-example) thread #70 - ShutdownTask) There are 1 inflight exchanges: InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-exchange-ID, fromRouteId=Route1, routeId=GetDataAutoBySinceTime, nodeId=toD7, elapsed=0, duration=216959570]
[0m[0m08:27:47,231 INFO  [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy] (Camel (camel-example) thread #70 - ShutdownTask) Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 298 seconds. Inflights per route: [Route1 = 1]
```

I don't know if some processes are stuck making it impossible another processes to start.

I thought to remove the generic routes (`PostMessageInActiveMQ` and 
`GetDataAutomaticallyBySinceTime` and to implements the same code in another routes (`Route1`, `Route2` and `Route3`) but I don't think this is the best approach.

Routes:

Route1 (Route2 and Route3 are almost the same, just change properties values)

```
from("timer:Route1Timer?period=15m")
 .routeId("Route1")
 .autoStartup(false)
 .setProperty("targetAddress", simple("hostname.route1"))
 .process(new GetCurrentDate())
 .setProperty("query",
          simple("DataQuery%26URI=Route1%26format=xml%26Mode=since-time%26p1=${header.currentDate}"))
 .to("direct:GetDataAutoBySinceTime");
```

GetDataAutomaticallyBySinceTime

```
from("direct:GetDataAutoBySinceTime")
 .routeId("GetDataAutoBySinceTime")
 .autoStartup(true)
 .removeHeaders("*")
 .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
 .toD("http4:${header.targetAddress}/command=${header.query}%26httpClient.socketTimeout=3000")
 .convertBodyTo(String.class, "utf-8")
 .to("direct:PostMessageInActiveMQ");
```

PostMessageInActiveMQ

```
CamelArtemisComponent components = new CamelArtemisComponent();
getContext().addComponent("artemis", components.getArtemisComponent());

from("direct:PostMessageInActiveMQ")
 .routeId("PostMessageInActiveMQ")
 .autoStartup(true)
 .convertBodyTo(String.class, "utf-8")
 .inOnly("artemis:ARTEMIS.QUEUE");
```

Entire code: https://github.com/vitorvr/camel-example

**EDIT:**

Camel Version: 2.22.0

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Camel version: 2.22.0

Comment: @ClausIbsen any ideas/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Vitor did you have any luck solving this?

Comment: Hi @BenW . I was moved to another project and don't have the opportunity to continue the analysis. Sorry.